# Combinatorics problem related to probability of a collision occurrence.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have recently been approached with this particular problem: What is the probability that, when randomly selecting 4 words from a set of 1000 unique words every day for a period of 7 days, one of the selected words will be repeated more than once?. Assume that on a given day, when choosing the 4 four words, there is no replacement on that given day. However, the set resets its length at the beginning of each subsequent day.

For example, if I choose 4 random words from the set for the first day, then there are 996 remaining words in the set by the end of the first day. On the second day, there will be the same 1000 words to choose 4 random words from again.

Initially, I tried using the combination formula to calculate the total number of combinations as a result of choosing 4 from 1000 for a given day, subsequently raising the following expressing to the power of 7 in order to represent the total number of combinations for 1 week:

$$(C(1000, 4))^7$$

I also considered the total number of combinations where each word is unique for a given day:

$$ P(1000, 4) = \frac{1}{1000} * \frac{1}{999} * \frac{1}{998} * \frac{1}{997}$$

I thought that it is possible to utilize the complementary theory where P(A') is what I am trying to find and that P(A') can be found by:

$$P(A) = (\frac{P(1000, 4)}{C(1000, 4)})^7$$

$$P(A') = 1 - P(A)$$

I am not sure if this is the right way or not? Thank you!

Comment: Clarification requested: On a given day, when you select the $4$ words, is the selection $\color{red}{\text{on that day}}$ **with or without replacement** ?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: Hi @user2661923. There is no replacement on that given day. To clarify, this is a theoretical problem relating to programming a word puzzle, but I will look over the article too.

Comment: Looks OK, use $1-P(\text{all unique})$. For all unique, the first day you can choose any 4 = $C(1000,4)$ ways. Second day you can choose only from 996 = $C(996,4)$ ways, etc. Multiply those 7 terms, divide by $C(1000,4)^7$ and you have your complementary probability $P(\text{all unique})$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the probability that all words are unique is $\prod_{d=1}^7\prod_{n=1}^4\frac{1000-(n-1)-4(d-1)}{1000-(n-1)}$ since we choose without replacement per day, which explains the denominator, we are not allowed to choose the four words from each of the previous days and we are not allowed to choose the previous words from the current day, which explains the numerator. Thus, the probability that we did choose the same word at least twice is $1-\prod_{d=1}^7\prod_{n=1}^4\frac{1000-(n-1)-4(d-1)}{1000-(n-1)}$.